# How to set up ClojureScript environment with Cursive and Figwheel?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, figwheel, cursive

I am trying to render some HTML in the browser using ClojureScript, but am not very close.

So far I have installed: Clojure, leiningen, Figwheel, IntelliJ, Cursive. I would like to use reagent and re-frame. I have tried Chestnut (this is the closest I have come to seeing rendered html). I am not sure if I need anything else.

What I would like to achieve is to use all of these tools as my environment and start creating a web app.

Figwheel seems to be the main problem.

Where I've currently got to: Created a Clojure project with IntelliJ and Cursive. I am following [this](http://code.haleby.se/2017/02/24/connect-cursive-to-figwheel-repl/) article to try and get up and running - I've got to the point where it says `Start Figwheel from the terminal (lein figwheel)`. When I do, the terminal in IntelliJ prints

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter, compiling:(cljs/closure.clj:1:1)`.

When I google this error, a the solution is to add this line to the `project.clj`:

`:jvm-opts ["--add-modules" "java.xml.bind"]`

Then I run `lein figwheel` in the terminal again and this time I get:

`java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found`

Then I got to IntelliJ > File > Project Structure > Platform SDKs and change the SDK path to 1.8. I have tried 12 and 8. Nothing works.

Am I close? How can I move on? I've done the getting started tutorials but they just focus on REPLs and not a full on web development environment etc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by you using a newer JDK Version (9+) and the older figwheel stuff still expecting JDK8.

One fix is the `--add-modules` you already found but I'm pretty sure the package name is `javax.xml.bind` but I might be wrong.

The other fix that is "easier" is just adding an additional dependency to the `:dependencies` vector.

```
[javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api "2.3.0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use Figwheel for the past year is not with Leiningen, but with the Clojure `deps.edn` system.

Full details are on the Figwheel-Main website:  https://figwheel.org/

Work through the tutorial.

---

For using Cursive, I first create the project directory & files, and then add it to Cursive/IntelliJ via:

```
 File -> New -> Project from Existing Sources
```

For a Clojure 'lein' based project, I click on the file `project.clj`.  For a ClojureScript 'deps' based project, you could click on `deps.edn`, or just the parent directory (I haven't experimented creating CLJS projects).

Comment: It's worth noting that at https://figwheel.org/docs/cursive.html they tell you not to try to use `deps.edn`, and rather to use `lein`. But I suspect these instructions are outdated. It might be useful to have someone give explicit instructions on how to create a ClojureScript project on Cursive with `deps.edn` and figwheel. This page may be informative: https://clojureverse.org/t/making-a-clojurescript-repl-work-in-a-deps-edn-project-with-cursive/5891/3